# I am using Apache POI to read Excel file but stuck with an error

Tags: java, apache

```
package org.excel;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import jxl.Sheet;

import jxl.Workbook;

import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class data {

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;

    InputStream XlsxFileToRead = null;

    public data(String path){





        try {

            XlsxFileToRead = new FileInputStream(path);

            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(XlsxFileToRead);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }


    public String  GetcellValue(int columnNumber,int rowNumber){

        workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        return GetcellValue(columnNumber, rowNumber);


    }

}
```

Console error:

[image: console error]

Comment: Would you swap that image with a block of text please? Images of text are not compatible with clipboards, search engines and screen-readers, and so make it harder for people to help. Don't forget to use the formatting tool, as I have done on your code block.

Comment: Hi can you guide me what I have to do exactly .As I'am new in this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Where are you calling GetcellValue? Except for the recursive call, it doesn't seem to get called...

Comment: I'am calling Getcellvalue in my main

Comment: page.loginkeys(datasheet.GetcellValue(0, 0));
page.loginkeys(datasheet.GetcellValue(0, 0));

Answer (score 0):

You have infinite recursion here:

```
public String GetcellValue(int columnNumber,int rowNumber)
{
    return GetcellValue(columnNumber, rowNumber);
}
```

This will never terminate (your Java implementation doesn't do any tail-call elimination).  Hence the stack overflows.

Comment: Thanks. So what exactly I have to do ?

Comment: Something other than calling the same method repeatedly, I guess.  Did you mean to call some method from the result of `workbook.getSheetAt(0)` that you're currently throwing away?  At the moment, that call only serves to test whether `workbook` is null.

Comment: page.loginkeys(datasheet.GetcellValue(0, 0));
  page.loginkeys(datasheet.GetcellValue(0, 0));
  
 
In my main method

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do in your method **GetcellValue** , anyway below an example with two different ways(you can find useful to solve your problem) to get data from an excel file via apache poi :

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Data {

    private XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    private InputStream xlsxFileToRead;

        public Data(String path){
            try {
                xlsxFileToRead = new FileInputStream(path);
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(xlsxFileToRead);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void close() throws IOException {
            if(workbook != null)
                workbook.close();
            if(xlsxFileToRead!=null)
                xlsxFileToRead.close();
        }

        public void  GetcellValues(int columnNumber,int rowNumber){
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
            for(int i=0;i<rowNumber;i++){
                Row row =  sheet.getRow(i);
                for(int j=0;j<columnNumber;j++){
                Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
                    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                }  
            }
        }

        public XSSFWorkbook getWorkbook() {
            return workbook;
        }

        public String  GetcellValuesOnebyone(int columnNumber,int rowNumber,XSSFSheet sheet){
                Row row =  sheet.getRow(rowNumber);
                Cell cell = row.getCell(columnNumber);
                    return cell.getStringCellValue();       
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String path = "patToFile";
            Data m = new Data(path);
            m.GetcellValues(3, 2);        
            System.out.println("**********************");
            XSSFSheet sheet = m.getWorkbook().getSheet("Sheet1");
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++)               
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++)                
                    System.out.println(m.GetcellValuesOnebyone(j,i,sheet));       
            m.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();        
               }
    }
}
```

Excel file :

[image]

(Double) Result :

[image]

**Note:** close InputStream and Workbook at the end .